# Two polynomials congruence modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomial-congruences

This is a result that I found in a compettion. But I didn't known it is false or true.

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$. Prove that if
$$x^{\varphi(n)}-1\equiv (x^{p-1} - 1)^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}}\pmod{p}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}$ is a power of $p$.

Note: $\varphi(n)$ is the number of integers between 1 and $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: "Polynomial", not "polinomial". What means "và"? What have you tried?

Comment: If $p=2$ and $n=14$, then $\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)/(p-1)=6$ is not a power of $p$ but $x^{\varphi(n)}-1\equiv x-1\equiv (x^{p-1}-1)^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}\pmod 2$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini If $p>2$ then can you find a counter-example?

Comment: If $x$ is not a multiple of $p$, then both sides of the congruence are zero. If $x$ is a multiple of $p$, then the left side is $-1$, the right side is $(-1)^{\phi(n)/(p-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $p=2$ the assertion is false, for if $n=14$, then $\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)/(p−1)=6$ is not a power of $p=2$ but $x^{\varphi(n)}−1\equiv x−1\equiv (x^{p−1}−1)^{\varphi(n)/(p−1)}\pmod p$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z$.

Assuming $p>2$, let $n=p^em$, $e>0$ and $p\nmid m$ so that $\varphi(n)=p^{e-1}(p-1)\varphi(m)$.

If $x\equiv 0\pmod p$, then the assumption
$$x^{\varphi(n)}-1\equiv(x^{p-1}-1)^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}\pmod p$$
gives
$$-1\equiv(-1)^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}\pmod p$$
from which follows $2\nmid\varphi(m)$.

If $q>2$ is a prime divisor of $m$, then $2\mid(q-1)\mid\varphi(m)$, a contradiction which proves $m=2^r$ for some $r\geq 0$.
If $r>0$, then $\varphi(m)=2^{r-1}$ and this proves $r\leq 1$, that's $\varphi(m)=1$.
Then $\varphi(n)/(p-1)=p^{e-1}$ thus proving our assertion.

Comment: Thanks @Fabio Lucchini